# Make a new page in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

i have done the home page with 8 custom html module . Now i have to make new pages like contact us, about, services ect. but it different from the home page. i need to use only two module other are not useful for other pages.

I am new in joomla would like to how could i make new pages in joomla.

Comment: i only mean how to make another page in joomla where i want 2 module from home page

Answer (score 2):

Create a new page in the article manager and a menu item to that page. Then go into the module manager and enable those two modules for that menu item. You'll now have the new page and those 2 modules will appear.

Depending on what template you are using they may need to be in a different "position", e.g, below the content, to the side, etc. In that case use the duplicate function in the module manager to make a clone of those modules and place in the appropriate positions.

Note: If you want the modules to appear in the actual content area you can use the loadposition plugin, e.g. if you create a blank article you can then enter `{loadposition mynewmoduleposition}` to place the module in the page. Just remember to select that page in the module manager and put set the module to that position.

Comment: Thanks but i have making my template by my self i have complete the home its look like this html page http://uttaraclick.com/malta/ and now i have to make another page like this http://uttaraclick.com/malta/sidebar.html what would be possible solution i have made slider, 3 modules for three boxes and 1 module for twitter and soicla icon and 1 module for footer all are custom html modules pls help

Comment: Does your template only has the design for the homepage? Joomla templates should be more generic so that they can accommodate a variety of layouts for different pages. One way is to wrap the sidebar div in a countmodules call and only show it when there is a module to display. I have a simple example of that use in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264063/make-joomla-module-span-multiple-columns/12265533#12265533 . Not sure if it helps you.

Comment: But basically you need to make it so that the template can adapt to different modules layouts on different pages. So under your navbar you could have a slideshow area, content area, sidebar and below that have the 3 box layout. If the sidebar is not needed (countModules) then it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that joomla is "menu related" site where pages mean menu itemID, when you say "pages" i believe you have experience in wordpress...

Comment: yes i am able to make wordpress both are csm i think that is why i in confuse

Answer (score 0):

All "pages" in a Joomla website are created with the single index.php file in the template you are using. In order to alter what displays from one page to another there are a few things to consider.

First, Joomla uses menu items to determine what a page is. When you create a menu item, it is assigned an itemID. In the case of menu items that have child items (an article within a category menu), then the child items inherit the parent itemID. You can then select to display modules on that menu item. In the module parameters there are options to display a module on all menu items, no menu items, selected menu items, and exclude menu items. You would change these selections to fit what you want displayed.

The second thing to consider is the template itself. It sounds like you have created a custom template so you will likely need to alter that. The index.php file should contain all of the possible module positions that you would may want to use. In order to hide the positions that are not being used on a particular page, you need to make those positions collapsible. You do this by not displaying any module position that is not populated on a particular page using this code:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('top')) : ?><jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="xhtml" /><?php endif; ?>
```

You would want to use similar code for each module position on the page. This allows you to have a sidebar position that is not displayed on the home page, but is displayed on other interior pages that include a module in that position.

Ideally, if you plan the template properly, you will have many module positions that will allow you to add content in many different positions without having to touch the template once it is coded.

Comment: i found something regarding this here http://docs.joomla.org/JDocumentHTML/countModules

Comment: Exactly, with creative use of countModules you can create evenly spaced boxes or columns when you have multiple modules in a single position, or simply not display the position at all.